# Is there any way to upload files to S3 bucket using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am trying to setup an ETL pipeline where

1. Source is a SQL Server table's column in binary stream form
2. Destination (sink) is s3 bucket

My requirements are:

1. To read binary stream column from SQL Server table
2. Process the binary stream data row by row
3. Upload file to a S3 bucket for each binary stream data

I have tried DataFlow, Copy, AWS Connectors on Azure Data Factory, but there is no option to set s3 bucket as destination (sink)

Is there any other approach available in Azure Data Factory to match these requirements?

Comment: As per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) S3 bucket is not supported as sink in ADF

Comment: Put it to Azure Storage and then trigger to S3 from there. There’s always a way.

Comment: @Skin - that sounds interesting, can you share more details?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use SFTP as sink using copy data activity. Below is something I have tried.

Here is the pipeline where I have used Lookup to get the SQL Table rows.

[image]

In my foreach loop I have set the filename and file data into 2 variables.

[image]

---

[image]

Take a sample csv file (1 row, 1 column which will be ignore anyway) and add an additional column with dynamic content value as processed binary stream data (keep only the required additional column and delete the rest in mapping).

[image]

---

[image]

Create a sink dataset to destination blob container where you'll store each row data as separate blob.

[image]

Now you can add another copy activity making the sink of copy activity 1 (previous copy activity) as source and then make sink as SFTP which allows you to connect to amazon s3.

[image]

---

[image]

For more information, you can refer [Copy and transform data in SFTP server using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp?tabs=data-factory)